# Pass value from one page to another in Crystal Reports report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report of a bill and i want to make that the value on the footer (which should represent the sum of all of the items on the page) of one page appears on the header of the next page, just like a bill should have.

Any idea on how i can do this?

Regards,

Comment: Will bills ever spill over to a third page? What total do you want at the top of page 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this (don't have a copy of CR in front of me), but try this:

1. Create a running total of your summary value.  Use the default options.  You should be able to do this by just right-clicking.
2. Move the running total to your page header.

Comment: I think Crystal will advance to the next record before printing the page header, so the running total would accumulate the value of that new record, too. You could either store the value in a variable in the page footer and retrieve it in the following header, or simply subtract it off like this: `{#ExtendedPriceGrandTotal} - {this line.extendedprice}`.